# get current connection from mysql connector c++ api

Tags: c++

Im using the mysql connector c++ api and I made, that my program connect to the database after I execute it.

But now I have to do querys on other cpp files.

Should I open a new connection and close it every time I do a query or should I keep that one connection?

And if its better to keep one connection, then how can I get the current connection on other cpp files?

main on 1.cpp

```
int AuthServerMain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection * con;
    driver = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://ip:3306", "root", "password");
    con->setSchema("dbo");
}
```

now my problem is the "con"

if I write on 2.cpp

```
sql::Statement * stmt;
sql::ResultSet * resset;
stmt = con->createStatement();
```

then "con" is red underlined because he cant find it. How can I do that he can find "con"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you not make a `database` class, which has the connection varaible inside it. Then you could just pass this class around the .cpp files where you need it. You could make a function like `database::excetute(std::string s)` or even overload the `<< operator`, so your code in the other .cpp files are clean.

Comment: Do you mean something like this ? https://github.com/eduardocasas/MySQL-Connector-Cpp-Wrapper-Class

Comment: Euhm yes, but I would make sure that you can't copy the class. If you do this by accident nasty things can happen. Also I would change the constructor, since it's static now, but that is up to you.

Comment: what is bad about static? I created a new project with those files from that link

Comment: What if you would like to use that class for another database to? If you made the contstructor have parameters like username, pass etc, you could use it in more than 1 scenario.

Comment: ah ok. I only need to use one database so its ok. But I still dont get how I can use the wrapper to keep one connection and dont have to open new connection on every new void function.

Comment: Well you could be lazy and use a singleton database class, but that is ugly. Else you could create a smartpointer to the databse class and pass that one around in your classes/functions.